# Переставить min и max число в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, методы

Условие: На вход программе подается строка текста, содержащая различные натуральные числа. Из данной строки формируется список чисел. Напишите программу, которая меняет местами минимальный и максимальный элемент этого списка.
Например.
Sample Input: 3 4 5 2 1
Sample Output: 3 4 1 2 5
и так далее. Для списка из одного элемента возвращается сам элемент. [Ссылка на условие](https://stepik.org/lesson/324754/step/6?unit=307930).

Я делал переменные для максимального и минимального значения,  для их индексов. Потом удалил максимальное и минимальное значения. Потом на их место (по индексу) вставлял: макс. значение на место минимального и наоборот. Сразу не прошел тест где была одна цифра. Поскольку такой случай единичный, сделал для len(a) == 1 вывод print(*a), остальное же затолкал в else. Код получился такой:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))           

maxi = max(a)
mini = min(a)
pos_max = a.index(max(a))
pos_min = a.index(min(a))

if len(a) == 1:
    print(*a)
else:
    a.remove(maxi)
    a.remove(mini)
    a.insert(pos_max, mini)
    a.insert(pos_min, maxi)
    print(*a)
```

Ввод и вывод для теста:
По состоянию на сейчас у меня: Failed test #6 of 8. Wrong answer
Этот тест я даже не могу посмотреть, т.к. на степике всего 4 теста для этой задачи. Подставлял разные числа, в том числе отрицательные,  трех- и более значные, нуль - всё работает.
Подскажите, что не так? Вопросы в логике? Синтаксисе?
Возможно, есть какие-то значения, где это не работает?

Comment: Подозреваю что ошибка в том что когда вы удалили ОБА элемента разом - позиция максимального и минимального числа изменилась и вы это не учли

Comment: Думал об этом. Только что прогонял через визуализатор - вроде работает как часы. Как раз была большая путаница когда было по схеме: удалить - вставить - удалить - вставить.

Comment: А вы посмотрите числа для 6 теста и проверьте, не проблема ведь :)

Comment: Давно бы посмотрел, но там открыто только 4 теста. Потому и свои значения подставлял))

Comment: Ткните по слову "тестовые данные", там все 8 тестов, ваш код по указанной мной причине не проходит тест

Comment: Ааааа... позор мне. Спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну вот, например, последовательность на которой ваш код сломается: `2 1 2 3 2`

В комментариях уже написали, почему такое происходит. Вы, конечно, можете учесть это всё, и для отдельных случаев из позиции вычитать единицу.

Но, на самом деле, есть более простой способ - вместо того, чтобы удалять-вставлять элементы, изменяя весь список, вы можете просто точечно заменить нужные элементы:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))           

maxi = max(a)
mini = min(a)
pos_max = a.index(max(a))
pos_min = a.index(min(a))

a[pos_min] = maxi
a[pos_max] = mini

print(*a)
```

Этот способ не только проще и надёжнее, но и вычислительно более экономный. При удалении-вставке каждый раз перестраивается часть списка, идущая после изменяемого элемента - и на больших списках это может быть затратно. А в моём способе меняется только пара нужных элементов, а остальная часть списка не меняется.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Решаю, потом смотрю чужие решения и вижу что у меня часто какие-то тяжеловесные конструкции, а у кого-то просто и изящно.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его как решение, ткнув на галочку слево от него. Это поможет другим пользователям и сделает приятно автору ответа )

Comment: Конечно. Очень помог! Отметил.

Comment: Второй вызов `max(a)` -> `maxi`. Лишние вычисления. Название `maxi` сбивает, заставляет думать что это индекс. `max_a` лучше - напоминает способ, которым его считали (`max(a)`).

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант,от Xander, ИМХО, идеальный.
Но можно и срезами делать. Полезно, если нужны более сложные замены.
В большинстве случаев работает. Попробуйте:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))           

maxi = max(a)
mini = min(a)
pos_max = a.index(max(a))
pos_min = a.index(min(a))

if len(a) == 1:
    print(*a)
else:
    new_a = a[:pos_max] + [mini] + a[pos_max + 1:]
    new_a = new_a[:pos_min] + [maxi] + new_a[pos_min + 1:]
print(*new_a)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо. Мне понравилось это решение, но почему-то на степике не проходит тест №4, где список из одного числа. Хотя для него в самом начале идет исключение. (немного погодя) - если считать что условие для if len(a) == 1 это костыль, то я поставил еще набойку на этот костыль, после print(*a) вставил exit() и всё заработало, степик проглотил решение. Только боюсь что такая практика испортит меня)))

Answer (score 0):

Так, для общей эрудиции, чуть другое решение, использующее `enumerate`, ключ сортировки для `min` и `max` и упаковку-распаковку переменных:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
a_i = list(enumerate(a))
pos_min, val_min = min(a_i, key=lambda x: x[1])
pos_max, val_max = max(a_i, key=lambda x: x[1])
a[pos_min], a[pos_max] = val_max, val_min
print(*a)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сохранил решение на будущее.